# calling a method in aspx.cs file from aspx dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net

I have a Serverside code in Java and client pages in .Net. Now I have to load a dropdown list in .Net from a serverside action class in Java. To do this, I created a asp dropdownlist as shown:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="invoiceYear" runat="server" OnLoad='<%#GetYearRange()%>'  
    Width="150px" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

and I have a method GetYearRange in aspx.cs  as  shown:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetYearRange()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("I am in");
    string strNewValue = "page=" + "" + "&rows=" + "" + "&sort=" + "" + "&order=" + ""; 
    string ss = ServerUtil.getServerString(strNewValue, "/invoice/invoice!getYearRange.action");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ss-->" + ss);
    return ss;
}
```

it is not going to that method. Please advice me how would I get the results from this method into my dropdownlist??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should not be decorated with the `[WebMethod]` attribute, and you also are not calling the method correctly. If you want to have this bind itself with values you need to set its DataSource to a proper collection. If you are trying to set its current selected value you will need to set that specifically. The real question I would have is: What are you trying to do with this code?

If you are attempting to load the dropdownlist with values received from your service call:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // GetYearRange() will have to return at least a string[]
    // It would be better if it was a ListItem[] or a List<ListItem>
    invoiceYear.DataSource = GetYearRange();
    invoiceYear.DataBind();
}
```

If you already have it DataBound but you need to force the selected item to be the result of your service, you need to use the `OnDataBound` event:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="invoiceYear" runat="server" OnDataBound="invoiceYear_DataBound"  
    Width="150px" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:DropDownList>

...

protected void invoiceYear_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     invoiceYear.SelectedValue = GetYearRange();
}
```

Comment: To be frank, I am totally new, just started asp yesterday. It is already existing project. With this code, I am calling an action in the server which returns yearMap. Can you please advice me how do I bind it with datasourse to collection?

Comment: I've already posted an update with a sample, it may need to be modified.

Comment: I tried..Its not pulling the data from the server..Moreover, its not even printing the debug info that I was trying to test before it goes to server. Meaning its not going to that method atleast. I am stuck with this since 2 days. Please help me resolve it today!!

Comment: @Naga: If you implement my first sample, that will at least call your method. You will need to remove the `[WebMethod]` attribute decoration though.

Comment: Oh!! Thank you so much Joel that solved my issue. But I have one more thing came up..

Comment: I will post it in other question